# Chef is not installing all resources, but it doesn't crash either

Tags: chef-infra

I finished running my `Chef` provisioned vagrant `bento/centos-6.7` using `vagrant-berkshelf` for local development.

It doesn't crash or anything, since there are no stack trace, no red output, nothing. But I get:

```
==> default: Chef Client finished, 163/254 resources updated in 14 minutes 41 seconds
```

Why `163/254 resources`? does it mean it didn't install something that was supposed to? If so, is there any kind of log?

Comment: I'd assume the other resources already were in the correct state. Maybe `knife reporting` has more information (sorry, it's been a while).

Comment: Yes, @Marvin is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the number of resources that were marked as updated slash the total number of resources (both only looking at the top-level collection used for recipes). Some resources (like `execute`) are always marked as updated unless you use an explicit `not_if`/`only_if` guard. Others (like `package`) are only updated if something has to actually change.